# Passing a file address with spaces to CMD

Tags: c#, visual-studio, escaping

I have the following code, which works fine as long as my address does not have any spaces in the folder names. I know spaces in oFileLocation is what is causing me issues, and I know I need to wrap it in double quotes, but no matter how I escape the characters, CMD.EXE tells me that "'/c' is not recognized as an internal or external command...." How do I need to alter strCmdText to handle spaces in oFileLocation?

```
oFileLocation = \\data\shares\folder1\file.iso
strCmdText = "/c \"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" x -tiso -y " + oFileLocation + 
    " -o" + oDownloadDirectory + "\\" + oFileNameReplaced;
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
startInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
Process.Start(startInfo).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you launching cmd.exe instead of 7z.exe directly?

Comment: Also, your code works fine for me as is (after fixing some of the compile errors). Can you post a compile-able example of the actual code that fails?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the exact answer but this is what I found quickly by writing `cmd /?` into CMD.EXE

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
on the command line are preserved:

- no /S switch
- exactly two quote characters
- no special characters between the two quote characters,
  where special is one of: &<>()@^|
- there are one or more whitespace characters between the
  two quote characters
- the string between the two quote characters is the name
  of an executable file.

2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
any text after the last quote character.
```

For you `/c` is not recognized as a command because it is an argument acutally. You need to use `cmd /c` where `cmd` is a command, meanwhile all `/*` are just its arguments.

I suggest you manually open CMD.EXE and try your whole `strCmdText` command there first. When you see it's working, invoke it in script.